# very weird behaviour of reverse iterator in C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, find

This is from a test I took today on my computer, I was asked to implement a Gardner class with two functions - each one will mark the piece of land the Gardner stands on as mowed and move the Gardner by 3 units to the left or right. If there is any piece of land marked as mowed on Gardner's path, he will skip it and move on to the next one.

I modelled the land using a vector of boolean variables. I was using std::find() with the forward iterator to find the land which is not mowed in the right direction, and I was using the reverse iterator in the left direction. The forward iterator works as expected. However, the reverse iterator produced some weird results. To be more specific, for example, in the debugger of Visual Studio, it showed the value the reverse iterator points to is false(which was expected), but when I dereference the reverse iterator, I got true. This can be reproduced in the following code, I have attached the code, any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Gardener
{
public:
    Gardener(int n, int position)
        : mLands(n, false)
        , mPosition(position - 1)
    {
    }

    /**
    *   \brief Gardener has mowed the lawn at current house and moved left.
    *
    **/
    void mowAndMoveLeft()
    {
        mLands[mPosition] = true;
        //auto it = std::find(mHouses.rbegin() + mHouses.size() - mPosition + 1, mHouses.rend(), false);
        //it = std::find(it + 1, mHouses.rend(), false);
        //it = std::find(it + 1, mHouses.rend(), false);
        auto it = mLands.rbegin() + mLands.size() - mPosition + 1;
        int counter = 3;
        while (--counter >= 0)
        {
            while (it != mLands.rend())
            {
                if (*it == false)
                {
                    ++it;
                    break;
                }

                ++it;
            }
        }

        mPosition = mLands.rend() - it;
    }

    /**
    *   \brief Gardener has mowed the lawn at current house and moved right.
    *
    **/
    void mowAndMoveRight()
    {
        mLands[mPosition] = true;
        auto it = std::find(mLands.begin() + mPosition + 1, mLands.end(), false);
        it = std::find(it + 1, mLands.end(), false);
        it = std::find(it + 1, mLands.end(), false);
        mPosition = it - mLands.begin();
    }

    /**
    *   \return house number that gardener is mowing right now.
    *
    **/
    int whereAmI()
    {
        return mPosition + 1;
    }

private:
    std::vector<bool> mLands;
    std::size_t mPosition;
};

#ifndef RunTests
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    Gardener g(10, 2);
    std::cout << g.whereAmI() << '\n';

    g.mowAndMoveRight();
    std::cout << g.whereAmI() << '\n';

    g.mowAndMoveRight();
    std::cout << g.whereAmI() << '\n';

    g.mowAndMoveLeft();
    std::cout << g.whereAmI() << '\n';
}
#endif
```

Comment: `rend()` *is* the first element in the container, `end()` on the other hand is one after the last element. That's the crux of the issue here: reverse iterators are a pain in the neck.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: To be more specific, "produced some weird results" is not a very good description of what happens. You need to elaborate on the details.

Comment: `if( something == false )` or `if( something == true )` looks ugly. They are already booleans.

Comment: @Slave Actually, in this case, where the expression is `*it` rather than something self-explanatory, I like the verbosity.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "some weird results".

Comment: I'd check that `it` initialiser, because it's an unclear expression and probably has an off-by-one issue if I know reverse iterators at all. Some comments wouldn't hurt around all those `+ 1`, `- 1` expressions either...

Comment: @Bathsheba, it is not. For the outside world `rend` represents a pointer to the element before the first one (though internally it points to the first element). You can't dereference `rend()` to get the first element.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I find `if( not *it )` more readable. Otherwise we can end up writing: `if( (*it == false) == true )` why not?

Comment: @Slava 1. [Nobody suggested that](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/slippery-slope). 2. Prefer `const bool value = *it; if (value) {...}` or `if (!value) {...}` surely?

Comment: @Evg: And the beauty of C++ is that you are both right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what is going on with your reverse iterator,
have a look at [reverse_iterator at cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator). More specifically, look at the [base() method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base):

> The base iterator refers to the element that is *next* (from the
>   `std::reverse_iterator::iterator_type` perspective) to the element the
>   `reverse_iterator` is currently pointing to. That is `&*(rit.base() - 1) == &*rit`.

In English:

`*rit.base()` (of a reverse iterator) would access an element of mLands which is one before what `*rit` hast to access. This shift between `*rit` and `*rit.base()` makes it possible to make `mLands.rend()` logically points past the first element of `mLands`. It is the mirror equivalent of `mLands.end()` pointing past the last element of `mLands`.

Now, for what you see in the debugger. Most likely, your debugger is showing you the value of `rit.base()` which points to one element earlier in `mLands`, than what `rit` is pointing logically. This can explain the discrepancy you are seeing here. For debugging, if you are uncertain what the debugger is showing, the safest thing here is to print the value of `*rit` or to store it in a temporary variable, and check that in the debugger.